# How can I choose Union ALL according to passed parameter ( need optimization )?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

Say we have a stored procedure that take `@IsAllowed` parameter which is boolean value and in case it passed `True` I should select data from two tables `A,B` ( I'll use in my case `Union ALL` ) Else it passed `False` I should select data From one table `A` ... I write it int he following way :

```
Create PROCEDURE TestSP
(
    @IsAllowed bit
)
AS

IF @IsAllowed = 1
BEGIN
    Select ID, Username From A
    Union ALL
    Select ID, Username From B
END
ELSE
    Select ID, Username From A
```

**Is it the best way to do that ?** although in my real case SP have about 9 parameter used in where condition of First query, that's mean i'll write the first query twice and any change in it I must take care to have the same copy in the 2 different places

Comment: Is `B` a subset of `A`? Or two distinct result sets from a single table?

Comment: A is a table that differ in structure from table B, but it have intersect columns that i want to return ... i use sql server 2005

Comment: **Intersect** columns? But you're not joining on them; you're appending them to the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM  B
WHERE @isAllowed = 1
```

Comment: is this will affect performance as it will iterate all rows in B table .. ?

Comment: Let me do a quick check. I'll run it an look at the execution plan.

Comment: It does appear to be doing a clustered index scan on the second table in the query. It accounts (in my simple tests) for about 45-50% of the execution cost. I would try it in your specific scenario and see if it is within needed parameters. All my queries came back in under a second or two even when I was returning thousands of records.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really crazy about this query, but if you want to completely avoid the cost of the secondary select, I think you'll have to trade it off for a temp table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableA') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #tableA

SELECT  ID,Username
INTO    #tableA
FROM    tableA

IF @isAllowed = 1 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  ID,Username
        FROM    #tableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  ID,Username
        FROM    B
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  ID,Username
        FROM    #tableA
    END

DROP TABLE  #tableA
```

Feel free to change the `#` table to an `@` table if your record set is small enough that you don't mind putting in memory (as opposed to writing it to the disk -- I/O is one of the primary bottlenecks). Just keep in mind you'll have to actually declare the table (with column definitions) as opposed to `SELECT`ing `INTO`.